# Multi-Threading in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, tcpserver

I have a TCPserver that I made in ruby, the server seems to work, I can see that two or more clients can connect and be served by the server, but, they sometime get stuck (as in need to wait for the other client to disconnect or just get unresponsive), usually after the "pass_ok" bit, When connecting only with one client I don't see this issue.

Here is my code:

```
  def self.main_server
    begin
      server = TCPServer.open(@port)
    rescue Exception => e
      CoreLogging.syslog_error("Cant start server: #{e}")
    end
    @main_pid = Process.pid
    # Main Loop
    Thread.abort_on_exception = true
    while true
      Thread.fork(server.accept) do |client|
        @client = client
        sock_domain, remote_port, remote_hostname, remote_ip = @client.peeraddr # Get some info on the incoming connection
        CoreLogging.syslog_error("Got new connection from #{@client.peeraddr[3]} Handeled by Thread: #{Thread.current}") # Log incoming connection 
        @client.puts "Please enter password: " # Password testing (later will be from a config file or DB)
        action = @client.gets(4096).chomp # get client password response 'chomp' is super important 
        if action == @password 
          # what to do when password is right
          pass_ok
          Thread.exit
        else 
          # what to do when password is wrong
          pass_fail
          Thread.exit
        end
      end

      begin
        CoreLogging.syslog_error("Thread Ended (SOFT)")
      rescue Exception => e
        CoreLogging.syslog_error("Thread was killed (HARD)")
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave it here for future reference and hope someone in a close situation will find it useful.

The issue was the global @client variable, which got overwritten every new thread and then inherited to the subclasses inside the thread.

using a local client variable (without the '@') got it to work as supposed.